# Spring Boot 3: Unable to gracefully fail and recover on Redis connection issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis, spring-cache

I have a spring boot API which is using Redis. I'm trying to cover cases whereby when Redis goes down for whatever reason I am able to handle it and more importantly recover and serve from cache again.

For context I have a service layer method which fetches data from a third party API. I have added the @Cacheable annotation to this method.

I have also created a CustomCacheErrorHandler

```java
mport org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.cache.Cache;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheErrorHandler;
import org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException;

public class CustomCacheErrorHandler implements CacheErrorHandler {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomCacheErrorHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void handleCacheGetError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key) {
        if (exception instanceof RedisConnectionFailureException) {
            logger.error("Failed to get data from cache. Falling back to NoOpCacheManager.", exception);
            return;
        }
        // Handle other cache get errors
        logger.error("Error occurred while getting data from cache: " + exception.getMessage(), exception);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleCachePutError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key, Object value) {
        if (exception instanceof RedisConnectionFailureException) {
            logger.error("Failed to put data into cache. Falling back to NoOpCacheManager.", exception);
            return;
        }
        // Handle other cache put errors
        logger.error("Error occurred while putting data into cache: " + exception.getMessage(), exception);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleCacheEvictError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key) {
        // Handle cache evict errors
        logger.error("Error occurred while evicting data from cache: " + exception.getMessage(), exception);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleCacheClearError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache) {
        // Handle cache clear errors
        logger.error("Error occurred while clearing cache: " + exception.getMessage(), exception);
    }
}
```

And A RedisConfig

```java
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig implements CachingConfigurer {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RedisConfig.class);

    @Value("${spring.data.redis.host}")
    private String redisHost;

    @Value("${spring.data.redis.port}")
    private int redisPort;

    @Value("${spring.data.redis.database}")
    private int redisDatabase;

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(CacheManager.class)
    public CacheManager fallbackCacheManager() {
        return new NoOpCacheManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisConfig = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
        redisConfig.setHostName(redisHost); // Set the Redis server host
        redisConfig.setPort(redisPort); // Set the Redis server port
        redisConfig.setDatabase(redisDatabase);


        LettuceClientConfiguration clientConfig = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder()
                .clientOptions(ClientOptions.builder()
                        .socketOptions(SocketOptions.builder()
                                .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5)) // Set the connection timeout here
                                .build())
                        .build())
                .build();

        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisConfig, clientConfig);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public CacheManager cacheManager(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager = null;

        try {
            redisCacheManager = RedisCacheManager.builder(redisConnectionFactory)
                    .cacheDefaults(cacheConfiguration())
                    .build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Failed to create Redis cache manager. Falling back to NoOpCacheManager.", e);
        }

        if (redisCacheManager != null) {
            CompositeCacheManager cacheManager = new CompositeCacheManager(redisCacheManager, fallbackCacheManager());
            cacheManager.setFallbackToNoOpCache(true);
            return cacheManager;
        } else {
            return fallbackCacheManager();
        }
    }
    @Bean
    public RedisCacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration() {
        return RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer()));
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
        redisTemplate.setDefaultSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
        return redisTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheErrorHandler cacheErrorHandler() {
        return new CustomCacheErrorHandler();
    }
```

What is happening is, If Redis goes down my API generates a 500 with the following in the logs:

```
2023-08-19T16:46:08.027+01:00  INFO 24125 --- [xecutorLoop-1-8] i.l.core.protocol.ConnectionWatchdog     : Reconnecting, last destination was localhost/<unresolved>:6379
2023-08-19T16:46:08.031+01:00  WARN 24125 --- [ioEventLoop-6-8] i.l.core.protocol.ConnectionWatchdog     : Cannot reconnect to [localhost/<unresolved>:6379]: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:6379
2023-08-19T16:46:16.327+01:00  INFO 24125 --- [ecutorLoop-1-10] i.l.core.protocol.ConnectionWatchdog     : Reconnecting, last destination was localhost/<unresolved>:6379
2023-08-19T16:46:16.334+01:00  WARN 24125 --- [ioEventLoop-6-9] i.l.core.protocol.ConnectionWatchdog     : Cannot reconnect to [localhost/<unresolved>:6379]: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:6379
2023-08-19T16:46:32.724+01:00  INFO 24125 --- [xecutorLoop-1-3] i.l.core.protocol.ConnectionWatchdog     : Reconnecting, last destination was localhost/<unresolved>:6379
2023-08-19T16:46:32.728+01:00  WARN 24125 --- [oEventLoop-6-10] i.l.core.protocol.ConnectionWatchdog     : Cannot reconnect to [localhost/<unresolved>:6379]: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:6379
2023-08-19T16:47:01.153+01:00 ERROR 24125 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.QueryTimeoutException: Redis command timed out] with root cause

io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandTimeoutException: Command timed out after 1 minute(s)
    at io.lettuce.core.internal.ExceptionFactory.createTimeoutException(ExceptionFactory.java:59) ~[lettuce-core-6.2.4.RELEASE.jar:6.2.4.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.internal.Futures.awaitOrCancel(Futures.java:246) ~[lettuce-core-6.2.4.RELEASE.jar:6.2.4.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.LettuceFutures.awaitOrCancel(LettuceFutures.java:74) ~[lettuce-core-6.2.4.RELEASE.jar:6.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnection.await(LettuceConnection.java:959) ~[spring-data-redis-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnection.lambda$doInvoke$4(LettuceConnection.java:818) ~[spring-data-redis-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceInvoker$Synchronizer.invoke(LettuceInvoker.java:665) ~[spring-data-redis-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceInvoker.just(LettuceInvoker.java:94) ~[spring-data-redis-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceStringCommands.get(LettuceStringCommands.java:52) ~[spring-data-redis-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.DefaultedRedisConnection.get(DefaultedRedisConnection.java:284) ~[spring-data-redis-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.DefaultRedisCacheWriter.lambda$get$1(DefaultRedisCacheWriter.java:122) ~[spring-data-redis-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.DefaultRedisCacheWriter.execute(DefaultRedisCacheWriter.java:276) ~[spring-data-redis-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.DefaultRedisCacheWriter.get(DefaultRedisCacheWriter.java:122) ~[spring-data-redis-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.lookup(RedisCache.java:86) ~[spring-data-redis-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cache.support.AbstractValueAdaptingCache.get(AbstractValueAdaptingCache.java:58) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheInvoker.doGet(AbstractCacheInvoker.java:73) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findInCaches(CacheAspectSupport.java:571) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findCachedItem(CacheAspectSupport.java:536) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:402) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:345) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:64) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:702) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at com.project.availability.service.availability.AvailabilityService$$SpringCGLIB$$0.fetchAvailabilitySummary(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at com.project.availability.controller.availability.AvailabilityController.fetchServiceAvailability(AvailabilityController.java:48) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$FilterObservation$SimpleFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$1(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:477) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$AroundFilterObservation$SimpleAroundFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$1(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:338) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator.lambda$wrapSecured$0(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:238) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:225) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:135) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:238) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:225) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:135) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:131) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:238) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:225) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:135) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:238) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:225) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:135) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:238) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:225) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:135) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:238) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:225) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:135) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:128) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:238) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:225) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:135) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:238) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:225) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:135) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:238) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:225) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:135) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:238) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:225) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:135) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:238) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:225) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:135) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:238) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$AroundFilterObservation$SimpleAroundFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$0(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:321) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:222) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:135) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

I as stated above would like to be able to fall back to the non cached version i.e. call my third party API.

Can anyone spot why this is not happening. I thought by defining

```java
 CompositeCacheManager cacheManager = new CompositeCacheManager(redisCacheManager, fallbackCacheManager());
        cacheManager.setFallbackToNoOpCache(true);
```

it would just fall back?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I think you misunderstand how Spring's `CompositeCacheManager` ([Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/support/CompositeCacheManager.html)) technically works.

The `CompositeCacheManager` does NOT fallback when a caching provider is not accessible (or unavailable). It simply searches the configured caching providers (using the composed `CacheManager(s)` in the composite) looking for a provider containing a `Cache` for the cacheable operation. Only when a caching provider can be successfully queried and returns `null` will the next provider in the list of composed providers even be considered.

> NOTE: By default, *Spring Data Redis* configures the Redis caching provider to "allow runtime cache creation" by default.

In your case, Spring's caching infrastructure determined that (in normal cases), Redis can and potentially might return a cached value for the cacheable operation, but threw an Exception instead because your Redis server was inaccessible, which stopped the cacheable infrastructure from proceeding in the composite.

Therefore, you need to configure a `CacheErrorHandler` (see [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheErrorHandler.html)).

Specifically, note:

> "*Typically, failing to retrieve an object from the cache with a given id can be transparently managed as a cache miss **by not throwing back such exception**.*"

With a proper `CacheErrorHandler` configured, you don't even need a `NoOpCacheManager`.

You should handle Exceptions thrown by the underlying caching provider (e.g. Redis) appropriately, and decide how these `Exceptions` should be handled relative to caching.

Comment: Hi John thanks for the response! Can I ask, what is wrong or am I missing something with my CacheErrorHandler in the code I posted in the description?

Comment: Sorry, it has been awhile since I last looked at this. I don't recall, did you have a `CacheErrorHandler` prior to me answering your question? On first glance, it appears that you are handling the wrong Exception? While, you may still need to appropriately handle the `RedisConnectionFailureException` too, it appears that now a `RedisCommandTimeoutException` is also being thrown...

Comment: While the `RedisConnectionFailureException` comes from Spring Data Redis, mostly when establishing connections, the `RedisCommandTimeoutException` is being thrown by the Redis, Lettuce client driver itself. The later can happen once control passes from SD Redis to the driver (e.g. Lettuce) when issuing commands on SD Redis's behalf through some intermediate data access strategy, such as Spring (core's) caching.

Comment: The good news is, both are `RuntimeExceptions` and could be handled generally. Alternatively, I would probably be specific about which Exceptions you are handling in your `CacheErrorHandler`. It seems most, if not all, Exceptions thrown from the Lettuce, Redis client driver extends `RedisException`, which is a `RuntimeException`. Therefore, you could generally catch both SD Redis `RedisConnectionFailureException` and the Lettuce `RedisException` and then have strategies to handle specific Lettuce `RedisExceptions` as needed. Just a suggestion.

Comment: 1 more thing...

Comment: The configuration of your custom `CacheErrorHandler` is not declared and registered as a bean in the Spring conrtainer (`ApplicationContext`). Rather, it is actually provided by an override (implementation) of the `errorHandler()` method when your Spring `@Configuration` class (in your case, `RedisConfig`) implements the `CachingConfigurer` interface.

Comment: I have an example of a custom `CacheErrorHandler` that I created when answering another SO post that you can have a look at here: https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/CachingConfigurerBeansIntegrationTests.java#L142-L151. This is almost precisely the scenario you are trying to handle, i.e. invoking the service method when the caching provider is not available.

Comment: Note that when you implement the `CachingConfigurer` interface, there is an override for the `cacheManager` declaration, too. This means the `CacheManager` caching provider implementation (e.g. Redis) does not need to be explicitly declared/registered as a bean either. Of course, if you are using Spring Boot, then this is a moot  point since Boot can detect and auto-configure a caching provider (e.g. Redis) for you.

Comment: Updated link: https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/main/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/CachingConfigurerBeansIntegrationTests.java#L143-L152